# Image location in url tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a variable in which I populate the image location dynamically.

I need to change the background image with that variable. I am not able to find a way to do that.

```
var myImg = '/images/example1.jpg';

document.body.style.background = "url(myImg) no-repeat";
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Is there a syntax issue or should this be done in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

`myImg` is the literal word in side the string.  Use concatenation to use the variable:

```
document.body.style.background = "url(" + myImg + ") no-repeat";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am just learning. Really appreciate the quick help..

Answer (score 0):

I like this way

> var bodyStyle = document.body.style;
>
> bodyStyle.backgroundImage = 'url(' + yourImage + ')';
>
> bodyStyle.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat'